# How to prove this (basic big theta problem)

Tags: algorithms

How to prove that
if
$$f(x)=a_n x^n +a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1x+a_0$$
and $a_n\not=0,a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}$ are real numbers,
then $f(x)=\Theta(x^n)$.

Comment: Proof by induction?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Can you prove that $f(x)/x^n\to a_n$ as $x\to\infty$?